# What Tense Should Follow "After"?

Tags: conjunctions

I'm not sure if the following sentence is correct.

"After the library was demolished, we now have to drive farther to rent books."

Do I have to use a specific tense for the second half of the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

"After the library was demolished, we had to drive farther to rent books."

vs.

"Since the library was demolished, we have had to drive farther to rent books."